# Image crossfading without HTML - ONLY CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, image, cross-fade

I need help with a homework for Webdesign. We have to design a Wordpress-Page only using CSS.
I want a crossfading in the header with 2 images.

Below the important part of my code. Of course it doesn´t work like this because of the two background-images. The animation is ready, but when the img fade out, there is only a white hole.

So how can I put 2 images in CSS?...
Thank you for help! (And sorry for bad English :D)

```
#pageheader {
background-image: url('img/test.jpg');
background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: 100% auto;

left:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes pageheaderFadeInOut {

0% {
opacity:1;
}

45% {
      opacity:1;
  }

55% {
    opacity:0;
    }

100% {
      opacity:0;
  }
}

#pageheader {
animation-name: pageheaderFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that "white hole" when your animation runs because both your background images are inside your #pageheader div, which your animation is making transparent.

Since you don't want to edit your HTML, we can use the :after pseudo-element to act as a separate element to hold your second image. Note that this won't work with more than these two images.

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/byrb9byc/1/).

```
CSS:
#pageheader {
  background-image: url('img/test.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#pageheader:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: pageheaderFadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
 }


@keyframes pageheaderFadeInOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  50% {opacity:0;}  
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

Note that you'll need to add browser prefixes (like I did in the jsfiddle).

Comment: Tank you very much!
Now both pictures are shown, but not at the same place...  
I´ll try to fix it, but any idea?...